# Python age finder and data saver

Tags: python

I am doing a project in which the user enters their details and it saves it to the file. I have made them input the age but I want it to automatically calculate the age at that time.

Another feature I want is to have file name be different. For example `1.dat` then the next input will be `2.dat`.

This is the code so far:

```
import os
from time import gmtime, strftime

first_name= raw_input("Type your first name... ")
second_name= raw_input("Type your second name... ")
age= raw_input("Type your age... ")
yearofbirth= raw_input("Type the year you were born... ")

birthyear=yearofbirth

os.system('mkdir Data')

savefile=open('Data/data.dat','w')
savefile.write('Firstname: '+first_name+'\n')
savefile.write('Secondname: '+second_name+'\n')
savefile.write('Age: '+age+'\n')
savefile.write('Year Of Birth: '+yearofbirth+'\n')
savefile.close()

print('Saved')

first_name=None
second_name=None
age=None
yearofbirth=None

int(float(birthyear))

adage=strftime("%Y")
agey = yearofbirth - adage
openfile=open('Data/data.dat','r')
name=openfile.read().split()

first_name=name[1]
second_name=name[3]
age=name[5]
yearofbirth=name[9]

print first_name+" "+second_name+" "+age+" "+yearofbirth
print agey
```

Comment: And what exactly is it you are having a problem with? Do you get an error, do you get the wrong output? What input do you give it and what output do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate `age` based on `yearofbirth`:

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_since(year):
    datetime.now().year - year
```

Note that you might miss the actual age for 1 year, because you're not taking months and days into account.

To allow for multiple profiles to be saved to multiple files:

```
def save_profile(filename):
    # here goes everything from the first `raw_input()` to file `close()`
    # use `open(filename, 'w')` instead of `open('data.dat', 'w')

def save_multiple_profiles(number):
    for n in range(number):
        save_profile(number + '.dat')
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague.  One problem you mention is wanting to know how to assign a new file name to each file.  To do so you have to know the names of the existing files.  There are a number of ways to do that.  Here is one approach

```
def find_next_file_number():
    existing = glob.glob(work_dir +'\\' + 'data_*')
    numbers = [int(file_name.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]) for file_name in existing()
    numbers.sort()
    return str(numbers[-1] + 1)
```

The above function assumes your data files are stored in the form data_INTEGER.txt

so to use if you would do something like

```
new_file_num = find_next_file_number()
new_file_name = 'data_' + new_file_num + '.txt'
outref = open(work_dir +'\\' + new_file_name,'w')
```